# Typescript nested class

Tags: typescript

My typescript class - with constructor - looks like

```
export class Message {

    constructor(
        public id: number = 0,
        public message: string = '',
    public fact: string = ''
    ) {
    }
}
```

I'm able to create a new model of this class like

```
  model = new Message(0, '', '');
```

How would I create a constructor for a new class with a nested inner class such as

```
export class Inventory {
  inventoryKey: string;
  inventory: {
        createBy: string;
        component: string;
        url: string;
        securityCredentials: string;
        description: string;
        createDt: string;
      }

}
```

?  Not sure what the syntax for the constructor would look like.  Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How would I create a constructor for a new class with a nested inner class such as

I do not see any mention of the desired nesting. I suspect you are calling the property `inventory` a class. Here is one way you can have a constructor for `Inventory`

```
export class Inventory {
  inventoryKey: string;
  inventory: {
        createBy: string;
        component: string;
        url: string;
        securityCredentials: string;
        description: string;
        createDt: string;
      }
   constructor() {} // EASY
}
```

You can easily take the property `inventory` as a constructor argument :

```
export class Inventory {
    inventoryKey: string;
    constructor(public inventory: {
        createBy: string;
        component: string;
        url: string;
        securityCredentials: string;
        description: string;
        createDt: string;
    }) {

    } // EASY
}
```

## More

Best learnt by reading the manual ;) 
 https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/classes.html